# How to make select list look the same as Bootstrap nav-pills?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, selectlist

I want to make select list look like this - > https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN9eM.png

Can I put somethin like:

```
    <select>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-left">
<li class="dropdown">
  ...
</li>
   </ul>
    </select>
```

Is it will be good or not ?